# How do I fix this NPM dependency issue for react-native-spotify-remote

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

I'm having trouble figuring out how to resolve a dependency related issue I'm having. I'm trying to install the npm module `react-native-spotify-remote` within a fresh React Native project and I am getting the following error:

```
$ npx react-native init test && cd test
$ npm i --save react-native-spotify-remote
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.63.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.63.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.61.5" from react-native-spotify-remote@0.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-spotify-remote
npm ERR!   react-native-spotify-remote@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-15T13_40_38_674Z-debug.log
```

As I read this error, it seems to me that it is saying that `react-native-spotify-remote` has a dependency of `react-native` at version 0.61.5 or higher, and version 0.63.3 is installed. Does that not mean the dependency is satisfied? I know that by downgrading react-native to an earlier version, as used in their example app, I could probably resolve this issue, but I want to try understand why this won't work first and I would ideally like to use the latest version.

Using the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` flags does not solve the issue either.

I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/cjam/react-native-spotify-remote/issues/80) on the GitHub repo but no luck there so far either.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json and running `npm install` or `npm cache clean --force`?

Comment: @JonahG Just tried that but no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s a problem with Peer Dependencies with npm, try:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```